# Remove a property from a persisted json object in cloudant

Tags: json, couchdb, cloudant

I'm having a problem removing property that was previously persisted in a document in a cloudant database.  It seems like I should to save a new version over it, without that property.  I've got the following code, it works, saving the object, I get a new _rev. But the `statistics` property is still on the persisted document.

How do I removed the persisted property?

```
// mixStatistics don't get persisted on the mix, so remove property as it goes through
// the save
let saveMixStatistic = mix.statistics;
delete mix.statistics ;
// -------------------------

this.userDb.put(mix).then(function (response) {
  // handle response
  console.log("mix saved");
  mix._rev = response.rev;

}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
});

// put mixStatistics back after the save
mix.statistics = saveMixStatistic;
```

Comment: Q pls that section "statistics" is your property or something that generating Cloudant?

Comment: .statistics is my property.  it shouldn't be saved with the document. at an early point in development, it got saved. Now, I'd think that I'd just save over it without the .statistics property but that doesn't work.

Comment: Did you inspect the HTTP request and response information associated with the `userDb.put` method invocation? Can you also provide details about that method?

Answer (score 1):

you may be putting `mix.statistics` back too soon. in which case, it is most likely being re-added before PUT makes the HTTP request. you should try to reset it after the PUT has completed. for example:

```
let saveMixStatistic = mix.statistics;
delete mix.statistics ;

this.userDb.put(mix).then(function (response) {
  // handle response
  console.log("mix saved");
  mix._rev = response.rev;

  // put mixStatistics back after successful save
  mix.statistics = saveMixStatistic;

}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);

  // put mixStatistics back after failed save
  mix.statistics = saveMixStatistic;
});
```

Comment: Gotcha, I like it.